# Searching for music files with mediastore

Tags: android

I have been researching this for hours now. I've looked at android javadoc - MediaStore and I just don't get it. I've looked for examples. Nothing.

I want to search the music library for a string. I have the main idea in my mind (get music library DB, search it like you would a sqlite DB) but I literally have no idea how to do it.

I have also found the URI for external SD media files - MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,

but I don't really know what to do with this.

Some starting points would be nice..

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `MediaStore` more or less *is* an sqlite DB. There are many ways to query it. By album, by artist, by playlist, by song, and so on. This will return a `Cursor` of all songs, for example.

```
Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(
    MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, 
    null, 
    null, 
    null, 
    MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE + " ASC");
```

You can then get specific columns from it like so:

```
while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
    String title = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE));
    // Whatever else you need
}
```

Comment: What does the + " ASC" do in the sort order?

Comment: Oh you don't need that, that just sorts by a given column in ascending order. DESC for descending. http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_order_by.htm