# Recording video with mediaplayer

Tags: android, record, android-videoview

Creating an app. I want to have the app play video from my sdcard, without having to change the code every time. I want to be able to choose from any video on my phone, is this possible and if it is would you mind sharing code.

this is what i have

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_play);
    VideoView videoView=(VideoView)findViewById(R.id.videoView1);
    MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(this);
    mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);

    //Uri video = Uri.parse(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"filename");
    Uri video =Uri.parse("sdcard/KVID0023.mp4");
    videoView.setVideoURI(video);
    videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
    videoView.start();
```

Comment: Use content provider to get a list of existing videos on the device

Comment: not really sure what you mean I am new to programing

Comment: See this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17952290/searching-for-music-files-with-mediastore. You just change MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI to MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI to get a list of video files.

Comment: But I do not use that in my code

Comment: Then make your question clear. What do you really want to achieve.

Comment: I have been able to get my app to record and it stores it to the phone but I cant play it back from the app i have to close it and play it from the phone

Comment: I have all the video going to a folder in my phone called MyCameraApp

Comment: Thank you for your help I figured it out