# How to check directory is exists or not in Android Q?

Tags: android, android-10.0

I have stored file using MediaStore for AndroidQ in Default External PICTURE directory now, i just want to check that directory is exists or not.

I have tried as below but it return false every time.

```
val file = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
    File(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES.plus(File.separator).plus(DEFAULT_DIR))
} else {
    File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
            Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), DEFAULT_DIR)
}

if (!file.exists()) {
    file.mkdirs()
}
```

**Here, every time it's returning file.exists() false in Android Q.**

Comment: "i just want to check that directory is exists or not" -- I strongly doubt that there is a way to do that, sorry.

Comment: Please try on Android Q , i'm facing this issue.

Comment: Oh, if your question is whether or not your code should work, I am certain that it should not. My comment was more about whether there was a way to do it using `MediaStore`, and I strongly doubt that there is a way to do to that directly. If you care about things like directories, you probably need to switch to the Storage Access Framework.

Comment: Yes we already moved for storage access framework and we are receiving content:// uri in android Q but if i'm checking on that by creating file its returning to false.

Comment: I do not know what you mean by that, sorry. Given a document `Uri` from the Storage Access Framework, `DocumentFile` can help you determine what exists.

Comment: Simply i want to save image into external storage with user given name but before i also need to check if user has already saved file with same name or not. So how can I check file name is already exist in directory or not.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200947/discussion-between-vishal-patoliya--and-commonsware).

Comment: "So how can I check file name is already exist in directory or not" -- if you wish to stick with the `MediaStore` APIs, you should be able to query the `MediaStore` for content with your expected display name. I have not tried seeing what `RELATIVE_PATH` comes back as on a query, but hopefully that would let you determine if the matched display names actually reside where you are concerned about. If you are switching to the Storage Access Framework, `DocumentFile` has `findFile()` and `listFiles()` to help you find what already exists in a document tree.

Answer (score 0):

You have hit the Scoped Storage Change in Android Q

https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/files/external-scoped

You will need to use MediaStore to access the files

See [Searching for music files with mediastore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17952290/searching-for-music-files-with-mediastore) for an example of searching for a file

Answer (score 0):

There was huge privacy change in android Q by introducing Scoped Storage.

```
<manifest ... >
<!-- This attribute is "false" by default on apps targeting Android 
   Q. -->
<application android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true" ... >
...
</application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: This is not a proper way to do this, because there is mention LegacyExternalStorage will completely removed from next Release, so you must have to deal with Android Q release changes.